# Processing data sent by jQuery post in PHP file

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating image gallery, and first of all, it basically loads thumbnails of images from server with PHP and sets their **alt** property to the path of the folder, then, what I am trying to do is, when user clicks on one of the images, it should load all images from that folder but it does not. I use jQuery and here is the simplified code. I just need to assign the path to the PHP variable. I tried everything I know but it did not work.

Sending path to the file with PHP

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("html").on("click", ".gcube img", function() { 

        var $path = $(this).attr('alt');

        $.post("TESTLOAD.php", { link: $path} );
     });
});
```

TESTLOAD.php file:

```
<?php
$link = $_POST['link'];
echo $link;
//other stuff that will load images will be here
?>
```

**UPDATE**

Ok this is the minified code enough to understand

Code from file which is sending the data(TESTPOST.php):

```
path = "projects/first/pic.jpg";
       $.post("TESTLOAD.php", { link: path} );
```

And code which should receive data but it dont, or at least it is not echoing anything:

```
$link = $_POST['link'];
echo '<div id="blah"> ' . json_encode(var_dump($_POST)) . '</div>';
//I was hoping that after I $.post("TESTLOAD.php", { link: path} ); it even echoes out something but it really does nothing
```

If I just use post in jquery, it echoes nothing so I have to load it again with

```
$("#output").load("TESTLOAD.php");
```

But I think if I load it again, the variable is not saved there anymore. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: So what is your output from the POST-request then? `var_dump($_POST)`

Comment: Have you checked if jQuery actually sent anything? Do `console.log($path)` right after you get `$path` and check.

Comment: @HieuNguyen yes it works, it shows the path it should

Comment: @Eric well I must figure out where to echo "var_dump" and I will update the comment

Comment: @hocikto Place it anywhere in your PHP file. Preferably in the beginning tho.

Comment: And check in firebug that you're sending proper POST data.

Comment: In that case, I suspect the url `"TESTLOAD.php"` might be wrong, so the request never reach the right destination. You can check that POST request from tab Network on Chrome dev tools or Firebug.

Comment: PAM: POST http://10.1.11.12/TESTLOAD.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]
@Eric I did it, if I go to the TESTLOAD.php directly of course it show array {0}, but when I do that on page where I am "clicking" that div, it does not echo anything. Even if I tried to echo some text it does not work. I think my problem will be that the php file I am trying to get is not loading, or is loading on wrong place. Weird

Comment: Ah so you want to see the result in frontend. Well then a success handler should be added:
`$.post("TESTLOAD.php", { link: $path}, function (resp) { console.log(resp); /* Do something with response here */ } );`

Comment: If I use $.post("TESTLOAD.php", { link: $path});, and in the file TESTLOAD.php is something like echo "<img src=" ' . $path . ' ">'; it will add the code, but will not fill the path with the variable, so it means variable is not sent from TESTPOST.php to TESTLOAD.php even though in console it shows TESTLOAD.php [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 2ms]. I am trying this - I click on button, it posts to the TESTLOAD.php a value, and then I am trying to echo out that value for example as a source to the picture, but it really does not work. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I know what was wrong I feel so dumb :D I did not know that I can use jQuery load function and send data at once. Now I am not using post at all, just this one line `$("#output").load("TESTLOAD.php", {link:path});`

> Output: Div where I want to show the loaded data / TESTLOAD.php file which I want to load {link:path} : data which I want to send to the php.